# Portable MFC datatypes substitute library(ies)

Tags: c++, mfc, portability

We're currently considering making our windows application portable to other platforms, and one of the biggest challenges we're facing is removing the massive dependency on MFC we currently have.

We're planning on thinning down our UI layer as much as we can (as there we really need separate implementations depending on platform) but try to keep much of the core shared between platforms. One of our issues is usage of MFC throughout 'core' libraries (relying on MFC non-UI specific data types such as CString, CRect, CPoint, etc.), and we're trying to identify possible solutions.

The first thing that came to mind was writing our own data types to substitute MFC ones. While this is almost definitely the best approach, giving us flexibility in their implementation, this would add some considerable time to the endeavour.

The second option would be using an actually portable library (or a set of them) that gave us these substitute to plug-in. I'm investigating this route to figure out if we can find some reasonably lightweight option to save off significant time with the conversion. Optimally we would be able to make do with a pure datatype set of libraries to use, without the need for all the added UI complexity, and which would provide easy integration with the actual existing MFC UI code. STL works in part (strings, list and other collections..) but it's lacking some coverage.

Has anyone here been through a similar situation and has some experience to share?

Comment: While not bad, this is probably not the type of question that should be asked on stackoverflow. [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place.